# Variable is not being passed in the Laravel component

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a component and returning a layout with a variable in the view. It works fine locally, but when I upload the code to hosting server, it doesn't work.

```
class adminLayout extends Component
{
    public $allow;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $id = Auth::id();
        $this->allow = allow_menu::where("uid", "=" ,$id)->pluck("allow_menu")->toArray();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.admin-layout', ['allow' => $this->allow]);
    }
}
```

[image]

I want the "$allow" variable to be passed to the "components.admin-layout" so that I can use it throughout the entire layout.

Comment: It does not work is too broad, please do more debug and share the debug results to make it easier to help

Comment: Have you tried just `{{$allow}}` to see if you can see the value? Like what @hassan said, your question is too broad.

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _it doesn't work._ Do you get an error? Is the component not created? Also, please don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).